# udev is unconfigured – how to debug?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, udev

On a VPS, I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. Now udev is reportedly "unconfigured" which leads to a number of follow-up errors, including, but not limited to, the network interfaces not being brought up.

Most old forum posts hint to initrd being out of date. I ran `update-initramfs` and `update-grub`. The most recent kernel is loaded and I *assume* (I am not sure) the initrd is okay. I decompressed the kernel to rule out problems with the new lz4 compression.

Symptom is `udevadm settle` responding with

```
udevadm settle is not permitted while udev is unconfigured.
```

Using `systemctl edit`, I adjusted `systemd-udevd.service` to start udevd with `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --debug`, yet `journalctl -xn -u systemd-udevd.service` remains empty.

How can I find the debug information so I can figure out why udev remains unconfigured?

**Edit:** It seems someone is experiencing the same problem with a desktop system: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281262/udevadm-looks-wrong-after-upgrade-to-20-04

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this phaenomenon. This site helped me: https://www.mcgill.org.za/stuff/archives/1167:

> The fix is to help the udevadm upgrade to complete (or at least not be totally broken), and then re-generate the initramfs with working code

If you have `udevadm` *and* `udevadm.upgrade` in `/bin/`, do this:

`/bin# cp udevadm.upgrade udevadm; update-initramfs -k all -c`

Then reboot.